# Why aren't my RadioButtons & JLabels showing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

i created a component which extends a JDialog. It creates a JPanel (with a big size) inside a JScrollPane. Then i add RadioButtons and JLabels to the JPanel

two problems : 
 1 - the RadioButtons and JLabels don't show. 
 2 - the scrollBars of the JScrollPane don't show

here is my code :

```
public class xuggleJOptionPane1 extends JDialog{  

    Container pane;  
    JPanel paneMain;  
    JLabel ms1;  
    xuggleJOptionPane1 myFrame;  
    JPanel panel;  
    JScrollPane paneScroll;  
    JPanel paneScrollpanel;  

    public xuggleJOptionPane1(JFrame parent, String str, int nf)  
    {  
        super(parent, str);  

        myFrame = this;  
        myFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 160));  
        myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 160));  

        panel = new JPanel();  
        panel.setSize(400, 160);  

        ms1 = new JLabel();  

        paneScroll = new JScrollPane();  

        paneScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380,100));  

        paneScrollpanel = new JPanel();  

        paneScrollpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1600, 1600));  
        //if i add this line the whole paneScrollpanel disappears  
        //paneScrollpanel.setSize(1600, 1600);  

        String pl ="";  
        if (nf != 1) pl = "es";  
        String s1 = "We found " + nf + " flux"+pl+". Which one do you wanna choose ?";  

        ms1.setText(s1);  

        ArrayList<JRadioButton> Buttons = new ArrayList<JRadioButton>();  
        ArrayList<JLabel> Labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();  

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();  
        for (int i = 0; i < nf; i++)  
        {  
            Buttons.add(new JRadioButton());  
            Labels.add(new JLabel("test"));  
            paneScrollpanel.add(Buttons.get(i));  
            paneScrollpanel.add(Labels.get(i));  
            group.add(Buttons.get(i));  
        }  
        Buttons.get(0).setSelected(true);  

        paneScroll.add(paneScrollpanel);  
        panel.add(ms1);  
        panel.add(paneScroll);  
        myFrame.add(panel);  

        myFrame.setVisible(true);  
        myFrame.setResizable(false);  
    }  


}
```

Comment: I don't have time now to answer your question, others will do for sure, but what I can tell you is that you need to learn the Java coding conventions. Classes start with caps, local variables should never do. Because you're not following the conventions, lines like "Buttons.add(.." look like you're using a "Buttons" class and makes your code hard to understand. Read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: thank you very much i will this in the future! and sorry for the bad naming convention

Comment: No problem mate, we all started like this ;)

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
paneScroll.add(paneScrollpanel);
```

to

```
paneScroll.setViewportView(paneScrollpanel);
```

While I'm here...

This is kinda pointless (IMHO)

```
myFrame = this;  
myFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 160));  
myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 160));
```

You could use

```
this.setSize(new Dimension(400, 160));
```

or

```
setSize(new Dimension(400, 160));
```

This is kind of pointless

```
panel.setSize(400, 160);
```

As the layout manager will make it's own decisions about what size to make the panel

You'd probably also like to look into `pack`

Of, on a personal note, I really, really dislike frames that aren't resizable :P

Comment: also if i don't add the line with myFrame.setSize the frame is small

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisLEBas If you like an answer, you can accept it by pressing the check mark next to it to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Try using `pack` instead.  Instead of saying `panel.setSize(400, 160)` try using `preferredSize` instead, should take care of it